# Converter binário para hexadecimal

Tags: java

Existe alguma função equivalente à bin2hex() do php para Java?
Preciso converter um binário para hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim

```
String hexa = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("1111", 2), 16);
```

E de hexadecimal para binário também

```
String bin = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("ff", 16), 2);
```